# how to execute return statement without waiting for asynchronous function

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await

In my typescript code I have the following:

```
await func(obj);
return { statusCode: 200}
```

However, doing this will cause a delay to happen with the return (since I presume it's waiting for `func` to finish running) - is there a way to return immediately while having func run entirely in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't `await` it?

```
// run func without waiting for it to finish
func(obj);

// return immediately
return { statusCode: 200}
```

Comment: if there is another await within the timeout function how would you get around that? From what I understand the code after the await will not run.

Comment: It should still run fine, but since the Promise being returned isn't chained with anything, you won't be able to wait for it to resolve and do something after that specifically. If you need that, either call `.then` on the Promise or return it.

Answer (score 1):

Just do not `await` the function call.  Example below:

```js
function timeout(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function test() {
  await timeout(3000);
  console.log("done waiting");
}

async function test1() {
  timeout(3000);
  console.log("done immediately");
}

test();
test1();
```